# unicode control character not showing in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, utf-8, windows-10

I have a page that uses unicode control character (`\u009d`) inside.in windows 8 and google chrome browser there is no problem showing this char but in windows 10 using google chrome this char shows as a rectangle 
[image]

but using other browsers like firefox or microsoft edge there is no problem at all

Answer (score 0):

This is weird that I have the opposited probelem.

'\u0001' shows nothing in firefox(53.0.2 64 version), edge, ie10.

But on my office pc '\u0001' shows special pic with chrome.

And on my personal pc with different version chrome it shows another pic which is different with the pic as above.

I guess the browser control the vision of the chars. Different browser with version show different results.